# adding an image to HTML through chrome extension (JS)

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, dom

I made an extension that needs to place a fixed image on every page.
The content script is:

```
imgTop = chrome.extension.getURL('top.png');
var top = document.createElement("img");
top.src=imgTop;
top.position='fixed';
top.zIndex='2353445';
top.top='200';
top.left='20';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(top);
```

I get the error: `Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8`

What I tried and doesn't work:

- Add style e.g `top.style.position`.
- Using `document.body`.

I know I can use `innerHTML`, but it is really messy...

Any idea what is wrong? Or another way to inject the image?

Comment: I think this has something to do with the code being run before your body is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that your variable is named `top`, which Chrome is confusing with the `window.top` property. Change the variable name to something else and it should work, like this:

```
var topImage = document.createElement('img');
topImage.src = chrome.extension.getURL('top.png');
topImage.style.position = 'fixed';
topImage.style.zIndex = '2353445';
topImage.style.top = '200px';
topImage.style.left = '20px';
document.body.appendChild(topImage);
```

Some other things: Style properties are accessed through `element.style.property`, and if you're doing things to the body just use `document.body`. Also, no need to have a separate variable for the image URL, just call it directly for the `topImage.src` like here, especially if you're only calling it just once.

Answer (score 0):

are you add the top.png into manifest.json?

you need define the web_accessible_resources property and list the resources (and optionally a separate Content Security Policy for those resources).

chrome extension doc url: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources